# PowerPoint 2007/2010 VBA code to change Type of Gradient Fill on a Shape object

Tags: vba, powerpoint, gradient, shapes

With PowerPoint 2007 & 2010, I have been trying to change the Type of Gradient Fill on a Shape object from default "Rectangular" to "Path" for days. Searched online but seems like no such question asked.

So far I can only get the Gradient Fill to be "Rectangle" (the default with 2 color gradient?). But I want it to be "Path". So far only able to do that by right click on the actual Shape --> Format Shape. "Format Shape" form shows and I can change the "Type:" from Rectangle to Path. But I want to do this change in VBA, anyone have a solution?

My code below. Variables starting with g are As Single

```
Set oSlide = ActivePresentation.Windows(1).View.Slide
    With oSlide.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeIsoscelesTriangle, gLeft, gTop, gWidth, gHeight)
        .Line.Visible = msoFalse ' No Outline
        .Adjustments(1) = gAdj1 ' Adjust the position of the pointing tip
        .Rotation = gAngle ' Change the angle of Rotation
        .Fill.Visible = msoTrue
        .Fill.TwoColorGradient msoGradientFromCenter, 1     ' Enable Two Colour Gradient
        .Fill.GradientStops(1).Color.RGB = RGB(255,255,255) ' Colour at center
        .Fill.GradientStops(2).Color.RGB = RGB(121,121,121) ' Colour at edge
        .Select
    End With
Set oSlide = Nothing
```

If no VBA codes can achieve that, I will have to use workaround... Copy and Paste those Shapes from a Template file - this sounds bad as I am going to make it a PowerPoint AddIn.

Thanks in advance!
Patrick

Comment: could you show the picture with expected result of using `Path gradient style`? you could upload it anywhere in the web and attach a link here or by editing your question.

Comment: See the different types of results: http://www.powerpointninja.com/images/2009/02/newgrad1.jpg
The default is Rectangular and seems no VBA way to change it. Full page with this image: http://www.powerpointninja.com/powerpoint-2007/three-new-gradient-effect-options-in-powerpoint-2007/

Comment: ok, but what is expected result in your situation while you have rectangle shape which you fill. Possibly you can't see the result as using `path style` in such situation... it will be the same for `rectangle style` of gradient.

Comment: Yes, with a Rectangle shape, the results is the same. But for Triangle, Pentagon, its very different. Is there a way to find out what the "Type" of the gradient fill of a Shape in VBA?

Comment: It seems that you should be able to set your gradient fill with the following method: `.Fill.PresetGradient 7, 1, -2` but it doesn't work. Possible bug or it's necessary to run some code earlier...

Comment: I assume there are no VBA control over this Gradient Fill Type. Have used the workaround... named the Shapes in the Template file and copy paste via VBA. Named about sixty shapes and added it to the addin file...