# Determine Image in Excel Comment

Tags: excel, vba

I have found plenty of vba for inserting images into a comment

```
Selection.ShapeRange.Fill.UserPicture "C:\Temp\Pictures\ewe.jpg"
```

How can you determine the image already used for an comment?

I would like to extract the embedded image names if possible.

Is there not a property to access that will give me this?
In the comment Fill Effects dialog box the image name somehow seems to be accessible.

[image]

Comment: I haven't found a direct method but if your just making a list you can save the document as a web page (`.htm`) and then open the `Sheet001.htm` file in a text editor and the image title will be preserved. The image path and name are changed however.  I know it's painful but maybe it will lead you in the right direction.

Comment: Which version of excel are you using?

Comment: Can do this with any of these versions. 2003-2010? I realize I can get to the embedded images but I need to associate the embedded image name with text in an adjacent cell to find the associated product it represents

Comment: I think there isn't a documented way to retrieve the picture file name for either Picture/Texture. Just like my very first SO question about [a Shape's Gradient in PPT](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17960260) that the Gradient of a shape cannot be set by VBA to one of the options in UI.

Comment: Suggest you to use other means to store the actual folder and file path to these images. eg. `.Comment.Shape.AlternativeText`. This name and picture is only related by some xml files within the Excel file.

Comment: The XML does have a resource link associating the current generic names to cells but I can't figure a simple method for determining it all. These are sheets created by someone else and I am expected to figure out what the original image name would be

Comment: Yes, the name of the image only shows up inside the vml files within **xl\drawings** which Excel VBA native objects does not have access to.

Comment: Those pictures are not linked ones, they are embed within Excel and their path does not exist any longer. The `...UserPicture()` is a Sub and it's irreversible. AFAIK, there is no way to retrieve the actual path of an embed image using VBA.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, I didn't have the reputation to just comment on your question for clarification.

I made a test file, inserted a comment and image in that comment, and then extracted the base files.  I then checked them all for the original file name.  I also found the embedded JPEG and decoded it to get the metadata.  As you've noted, the original file names are stored in xl\drawings\vmlDrawing1.vml (once you've extracted the xml files from the excel file by appending .zip to the filename and then running an unzip utility on it).  I did find the file name, but not the path or file type, so I'm fairly certain that the path and file type aren't preserved.

If just the file name is sufficient for you, then that file contains information for each drawing that you have, and those will include the cell location, although they're 0 based, so you'd have to add one to get the actual row and column.  My question is two part:

1)  Is the file name alone sufficient, or did you need the entire path?  If you needed the entire path, I think you're out of luck, since the paths are on a different computer and you can't even search for them if you do extract the file name.

2)  If that is all you need, does the solution have to be VBA?  In the past, I have programmatically unzipped and manipulated the xml base files, but it's a little tricky.  It's simplified by the fact that you only have to read out the data, so that's a plus.  I did it in .net before, but I'm sure that if it had to be VBA it could be done, but it would be simpler if you were open to the type of solution.

Let me know, I'd be happy to help you out.

====================================================================================

Try this:  make a copy of the spreadsheet, append .zip (test.xlsm.zip), and then extract the files manually.  Change vmlPath to the location of your xl\drawings\vmlDrawing1.vml file.  Then run this.  I did make some assumptions, for instance, I assumed that the order of the nodes and attributes would always be the same and so I used hardcoded indexes (shp.attributes(0), etc) instead of using logic to make sure I had the correct node or attribute, but you seem like you know your way around VBA, so I'm just going to code a barebones.  This will need a reference to Microsoft XML 6.0.

```
Sub vmlParse()

    Dim vmlPath As String: vmlPath = "C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\test - Copy.xlsm\xl\drawings\vmlDrawing1.vml"
    Dim this As Worksheet: Set this = ActiveSheet
    Dim doc As New DOMDocument, shps As IXMLDOMNodeList
    Dim shp As IXMLDOMNode, n As IXMLDOMNode, a As IXMLDOMAttribute
    Dim fileName As String, productID As String
    Dim rng As Range, r As Long, c As Long

    doc.Load vmlPath

    Set shps = doc.getElementsByTagName("x:ClientData")
    For Each shp In shps

        If shp.Attributes(0).nodeValue = "Note" Then

            r = 0: c = 0

            For Each a In shp.ParentNode.FirstChild.Attributes
                If a.nodeName = "o:title" Then
                    fileName = a.nodeValue
                    Exit For
                    End If
                Next

            For Each n In shp.childNodes

                If n.nodeName = "x:Row" Then r = n.text
                If n.nodeName = "x:Column" Then c = n.text

                Next

            Set rng = this.Cells(r + 1, c + 1)
            productID = rng.Value

            'now you have the productID, the fileName, and the cell location

            End If
        Next

End Sub
```

Let me know how that worked out for you.

Comment: The productid is in the cell that the comment is on. If you can extract the image associated with a cell address I could reconstruct the original image name, or one that is usable. This is possibly a couple thousand records. I am open to suggestions. Was hoping to use vba because it seemed like it should be easy. BUT am open to any ideas

Comment: Well, now that I think about it, you could probably use shell to execute the unzip utility, and then use some file i/o to read it, but you say it's just one file?  In that case, just unzip the file manually and then either:

use regex in a text editor like Notepad++ (which I use all the time) to get the name and row numbers, or,

use msxml to parse the xml in VBA, which gives the advantage of being able to write the data into the sheet, or somewhere else in the workbook, in the same loop.

If it's one workbook and you can share it I can probably write you out the script in a few minutes.

Comment: Hey, check out the short macro I wrote out.  It assumes one workbook and unzipping manually.  Let me know if that's what you were after.

Comment: I just haven't had even a moment to try this, but it looks very promising. Will let you know. Much appreciate your input

Comment: Had to change the doc As New DOMDocument to, doc As New DOMDocument60. I got stuck on this as it throws me out at For Each shp In shps. Apparently the shp As IXMLDOMNode is a problem and I have been so busy with work I could even troubleshoot it. I truly appreciate your work, because it looks like this will get me there.

Comment: Well, let me know.  If it would help I can dropbox you my working example.  DOM is weird, though, at least I know it is in the MSHTML library.  You'll have to use IHTMLDocument2 one time and IHTMLDocument the next.  And sometimes it will work for a while and then start throwing errors, and you change it to a different implementation of the object and it fixes it for no good (I mean documented) reason.  I don't really use XML often enough to know if there are similar issues there.

Answer (score 0):

If **c4** contains your comment:

```
Set shp = Range("C4").Comment.Shape
     if shp.Fill.TextureType = msoTextureUserDefined then

end if
```

Comment: Appreciate the input. How can I determine the assigned image name from this? That is the part I am missing